# set points in 2D interval with optimality condition

Tags: integration, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Let $\Omega$ be an 2D interval and let $\omega_1, ..., \omega_n$ a set points in $\Omega$. I am looking for that set points $\omega_1, ..., \omega_n$ such that following integral is minimized
$$\int_\Omega  \min_{i = 1,...,n} |x-\omega_i|  \mathrm{d} x$$

Can someone help me finding this?

Many thanks, Koen

Comment: What is a "2D interval" ? Is $\lvert \cdot \rvert$ the euclidian distance ?